# JavaFX: Provide non-controller class access to FXML controls

Tags: javafx, controller, task, fxml

I have a controller (Home.java) with an associated FXML file (home.fxml), and within the controller I call another .java class that is *not* a controller. The .java class is called "FillReport.java" and starts with the line `public class FillReport extends Application implements NativeMouseListener {`

This class utilizes a nativeMousePressed listener like so:

```
  @Override
    public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent nme) {
      FutureTask query = new FutureTask(new Callable() {
                            @Override
                            public Object call() throws Exception {
                                try {
                                    keyboard.type(full);
                                    sendBox.setManaged(true);
                                    sendBox.setVisible(true);
                                    sentBox.setManaged(true);
                                    sentBox.setVisible(true);

                                    return true;
                                } catch (AWTException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                return "ok";
                            }
                        });
                          Platform.runLater(query);
}
```

I'm getting a nullPointerException on the line `sendBox.setManaged(true);` because this `sendBox` is a `VBox` control from home.fxml. I tried creating setter methods within FillReport.java which will accept the controls from the controller, but I still get the nullPointerException.

**Home.java**

```
 @Override
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
 FillReport reportFiller = new FillerReport();
 reportFiller.setSendBox(sendBox);
 reportFiller.setSentBox(sentBox); 
 reportFiller.fillReport(dataArray);
}
```

**FillReport.java**

```
public class FillReport extends Application implements NativeMouseListener {

    public VBox sendBox;
    public VBox sentBox;

public void reportFiller(ArrayList<String> compDataArray) {
// Does some stuff and then returns to the controller
}

 @Override
    public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent nme) {
      FutureTask query = new FutureTask(new Callable() {
                            @Override
                            public Object call() throws Exception {
                                try {
                                    keyboard.type(full);
                                    sendBox.setManaged(true);
                                    sendBox.setVisible(true);
                                    sentBox.setManaged(true);
                                    sentBox.setVisible(true);

                                    return true;
                                } catch (AWTException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                return "ok";
                            }
                        });
                          Platform.runLater(query);
}

  public void setSendBox(VBox sB){
     sendBox = sB;
    }

    public void setSentBox(VBox stB){
        sentBox = stB;
    }

} // End of Class
```

You can see that I use keyboard.type(full) to sendkeys which works fine, and it's within a Platform.runLater() so that the controller can continue accepting commands while the sendkeys is occuring. However, once the sendkeys has completed I'd like FillReport.java to show Home.java's controls (sendBox/sentBox) but I'm getting the exception.

I think it's because the nativeMouesPressed listener isn't acting on the correct Home.java object instance. I only had a few minutes to type this, sorry if it's confusing.

Can you make any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you making `FillReport` a subclass of `Application`? The `Application` class represents the entire application and is instantiated as part of the `launch` process. Your application is already running when you instantiate `FillReport`.

Comment: This shouldn't compile, if it's a subclass of `javafx.application.Application` since `start` is not implemented.

Comment: Aside from the bizarre structure, and the incomplete code, are you certain that `sendBox` and `sentBox` in the controller class are not null?